# Subversion и работа в команде

Tags: svn

Помогите мну с таким вопросом. Как 4-м человекам работать с одним и тем же проектом,
проект находится на локальном сервере в соседней комнате в черном стеклянном
шкафу со стеклянной дверью на последней полке? Пробовали ставить `Tortoise SVN` на сервер и расшарить папку `htdocs`. Но черепашка сначала поработала, потом отвалилась. Стали закрадываться смутные сомнения, что мы что-то делаем не так. Вариант скопировать к себе на комп рабочую копию, исправить и залить на сервер мне нравится намного меньше, чем `Ctrl+S -- Alt+TAB -- F5`.

**UPD:** в папке `htdocs` лежит проект. Надо чтобы при кммите Васи у всех обновлялась версия сайта (в браузере)

Comment: а зачем расшаривать?

Comment: Чтобы всем двть доступ к htdocs.

Comment: хотел посоветовать распределенную систему. тут похоже рано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае наверное, стоит работать хотя бы так:

1. локальная рабочая копия у каждого, редактируем её;
2. Update (чтобы подтянуть последние редакции от соседа Васи;
3. Поредактировали;
4. Ctl+S, Commit, FTP upload, Alt-Tab, F5;

Тогда появятся плюшки, ради которых SVN затевался:

1. кто заслужил люлей за конкретную строчку в коде;
2. а давай-те ка откатимся к тому, что было пару дней назад вот в этом файле.

---

(из комментария) На сервере SVN можно настроить т.н. Hook'и - действия, выполняемые по событиям, например, сразу после очередного коммита: `post-commit'. О реализации на винде [чек хиер](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633614/svn-hooks-for-windows)

Так можно сделать, чтобы после каждого коммита обновлялись файлы на веб сервере. И действия Васи ограничатся редакцией локально и коммитом.

Comment: @sergiks, А не льльзя ли как-нибудь по-проще?))) (Автоматизировать процесс)
И, кстати, 60 МБ трафика по FTP, пусть даже по локалке -- не самое приятное что нас будет ждать.. Вот если бы можно было про-UPDATE-ить htdocs сразу...

Comment: конечно, можно сделать, чтобы при каждом коммите что-то происходило, напр. обновления выставлялись и на сервер. По вопросу мне показалось, что вы не готовы идти так далеко ) Чем дальше в лес, тем толще партизаны!

Comment: На сервере SVN можно настроить т.н. Hook'и - действия, выполняемые по событиям, например, сразу после очередного коммита: `post-commit'. О реализации на винде [чек хиер](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633614/svn-hooks-for-windows)

Так можно сделать, чтобы после каждого коммита обновлялись файлы на веб сервере. И действия Васи ограничатся редакцией локально и коммитом.

Comment: >По вопросу мне показалось, что вы не готовы идти так далеко )

^.^
А за советы спасибо. То что искал.

Comment: если речь о партизанах зашла, то деплой через хуки делать не очень удобно, для этих целей обычно используют билд-машины, типа CruiseControl, Bitten и проч... хотя, конечно, хуки - первый шаг к автоматизации.

Answer (score 7):

Ну вы млин даете...

Tortoise SVN это клиент Subversion! Subversion (он же SVN) это сервер, который обычно работает под Lunux'ом и [запускается там так](http://www.tonyspencer.com/2007/03/02/setup-a-subversion-server-in-4-minutes/). В общем читайте [SVN server configuration manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html).

Вам надо "поднять" сервер и подключиться к нему используя какого-то клиента.

Comment: А если еа сервере Винда?? И тут же вопрос: У Апача, что будет своя рабочая копия? (Repo !== проект в htdocs).

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=ru&sclient=psy-ab&q=svn%20server%20windows&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=5e52503172485ad4&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1366&bih=611